# Kubernetes. How to clean up a folder in another container with cronjob?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a StatefulSet resources `dev-phd-graphql-router`

```
$ kubectl get all | grep dev-phd-graphql-router
pod/dev-phd-graphql-router-statefulset-0                            1/1     Running   0          5h4m
service/dev-phd-graphql-router-service1              ClusterIP   10.107.196.167   <none>        5000/TCP   5h4m
statefulset.apps/dev-phd-graphql-router-statefulset   1/1     5h4m
```

In the dev-phd-graphql-router-statefulset-0 pod there is folder `/var/dump` that needs to be cleared every three days. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any examples on Google.

Could you show an example of a cronjob that connects to a `dev-phd-graphql-router-statefulset-0` and deletes the contents of the `/var/dump` folder?

Comment: in the job's pod, assume you have `kubectl`. `kubectl exec podname -- bash -c 'rm -rf /var/dump/*'`.

Comment: Also, take a look at [this example of creation k8s Cronjob To Schedule Delete Expired Files](https://dev.to/vumdao/create-k8s-cronjob-to-schedule-delete-expired-files-1i41). Please, let us know if the example of CronJob or the above command is helpful for you.

Comment: kkopczak. Unfortunately, this option does not suit me, because I do not attach an attached volume due ReadWriteOnce.

Comment: What about @LeiYang suggestion? Did you check it?